# Django shows page not found

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Chapter 18 18.4.2 in Python Crash Course,when i open http://localhost:8000/topics ,I'm using Django 3.0 and python 3.8 
shows

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/topics
Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
The current path, topics, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

and this is my code
learning_log\urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from learning_logs import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name = 'index')
]
```

learning_logs\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$',views.index,name = 'index'),

    url(r'^topics/$',views.topics,name='topics')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Topic
# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    return render(request,'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):

    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics':topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)
```

base.html

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>- 
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics'%}">Topics</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

topics.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Topics</p>
        <ul>
            {% for topic in topics %}
                <li>{{ topic }}</li>
                {% empty %}
                <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

and runserver shows:

```
Not Found: /topics
[06/Jan/2020 17:53:15] "GET /topics HTTP/1.1" 404 2077
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crUhR.png)

Comment: Why don't you write the urls pattern in the `learning_log\urls.py` ? it can't find the route cause you writing the `topics` route in `learning_logs.py`, how many apps are there in your project?

Comment: it is learning_log\urls.py ,i edit it wrong

Comment: so you need to import the urls from `learning_logs` into `learning_log` don't know why you name your app with plural. In your learning_log.py add `path('learning_logs/', include('learning_logs.urls'))` to `urlpatterns`. And then you can go to ` http://localhost:8000/learning_logs/topics`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, good question. Love the detail.

The error is the following

> Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order

This means that the url `/topics` cannot be found. You need to import that url from the app specific urls.py **into the main urls.py**. This is usually done by something along the lines of

```
# in main urls.py
from learning_logs.urls import urlpatterns as ll_urlpatterns
# other patterns ...
urlpatterns += ll_urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code replace 'app' with your appname.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from learning_logs import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(('app.urls', 'app'), namespace='app')),
]
```